# Oauth on Appengine with Google Play services

Tags: android, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-play-services, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm using Google play services on Android to get access to Google Apis and Google cloud Endpoints.  I would also be able to get access to the appengine User api using a token from Google Play Services.  Is this possible?  There is some sample code at this [link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/oauth/overview) for OAuth, but is a little vague.  Can I pass the oauth token in a header and get a user with the code below??

```
    User user = null;
    try {
        OAuthService oauth = OAuthServiceFactory.getOAuthService();
        user = oauth.getCurrentUser();

    } catch (OAuthRequestException e) {
        // The consumer made an invalid OAuth request, used an access token that was
        // revoked, or did not provide OAuth information.
        // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can, but this approach isn't going to be as secure as a scenario where you are:

- using a service-specific scope for a Google API
- accessing an Endpoints API directly

You can use Google Play Services to [obtain a token](https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services/authentication#obtain) for the scope you'd like to use. Since you're interested in using the `Users` API on App Engine, you'll want the `userinfo.email` scope:

```
String mScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
try {
    token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, mScope);
} catch {
    ...
}
```

Send this to App Engine via the Authorization header:

```
Authorization: Bearer your_token
```

Then, using the `OAuth` API, you can obtain a `User` object:

```
String mScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
User user = null;
try {
  OAuthService oauth = OAuthServiceFactory.getOAuthService();
  user = oauth.getCurrentUser(mScope);
} catch (OAuthRequestException e) {
  // The consumer made an invalid OAuth request, used an access token that was
  // revoked, or did not provide OAuth information.
  // ...
}
```

**But, in general you don't want to do this!** If you protect your application this way, another user can write an application that asks you permission to your `userinfo.email` scope. Once granted, all they need to do is take the token and pass it to *your* application, and they appear as you do. Endpoints and other Google APIs have additional logic in place to prevent this kind of behavior, which is why you're better off using one of those approaches.

Comment: Thanks for response, it has helped clear some things up for me.  I am definitely using the GS + Endpoints approach.

Comment: Hi @Dan , I used GS +Endpoint with sprint Oauth2 authentication at server end, I am getting "Full Authorization is required".Do you have any idea?