# Google+ and AppEngine Authentication

Tags: android, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an Android application with Google+ already setup and I was wondering if I could use this connection to authenticate with Google AppEngine endpoints.

Google sample code is:

```
   settings = getSharedPreferences(TAG, 0);
    credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(this, ClientCredentials.AUDIENCE);
    setAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null));
    Tictactoe.Builder builder = new Tictactoe.Builder(
        AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(),
        credential);
    service = builder.build();
```

So this is fine, but I'm doing authentication all over again. Can I leverage the PlusClient in any way to avoid creating further credentials?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the below steps to utilise your google plus sign to authenticate users for Google AppEngine endpoints:

1, Get the account name using google plus which will be in the step

```
String accountName = mPlusClient.getAccountName();
```

Now you dont have to use the account picker provided in the sample code as you go the account name through google plus

2, Save the account name from your above step to the sharedpreferences and to credential:

```
private void setAccountName(String accountName) {
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
editor.commit();
credential.setAccountName(accountName);
this.accountName = accountName;
}
```

3, Create a client id for a web app to be used as audience. I guess this should be in the same project in api console where you have already created a client id for your android app. Set this web app client id as ClientCredentials.AUDIENCE value.

4,In your app engine project with cloud endpoints, for the allowed_client_ids argument of the @endpoints.api decorator or @endpoints.method decorator,  supply both Android client ID and web client ID.  You must also set the audiences argument for the @endpoints.api decorator to the web client ID.

5, In your android app, use the account name and audience details to create a google credentials object and pass it to your service object to call the required cloud endpoint

6, You can also add a user check in your app engine code to ensure a valid user is accessing

```
from google.appengine.ext import endpoints
current_user = endpoints.get_current_user()
    if raise_unauthorized and current_user is None:
        raise endpoints.UnauthorizedException('Invalid token.')
```

Since you have google+, you can also look up the emailid using the userinfo.email scope as given [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people#retrieve_an_authenticated_users_email_address) . Also check these 2 posts for useful info : [GCE with G+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104274/appengine-cloud-endpoints-with-new-google-sign-in?rq=1) and [Oauth on GAE with google play services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501317/oauth-on-appengine-with-google-play-services?rq=1)